# Loading .qml file for raster using Python

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, style

How can I modify this script in order to load .qml for all the raster (not vector in my case) files in the canvas?

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point: # I need to change from vector to raster

    layer.loadNamedStyle('c:\\myQml.qml')
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the following should work:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
        layer.loadNamedStyle('c:\\myQml.qml')
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: @ilFonta - Most welcome, glad it worked :)